# Process image smoothing using image Pointer- need help to correct my code

Tags: c++, opencv

i am trying to perform average smoothing by pointers.

My aim is to process image by pointers .

This is what i coded.

**Code:**

```
int main() {

    Mat img = imread("best-testimg.jpg");

    Mat src = img.clone();

    int const templeteWindowSize = 3;

    int tr = templeteWindowSize >> 1; //templateRegion

    int bb = tr;                 //backgroundBorder

    //create large size image for bounding box;
    Mat im;
    copyMakeBorder(src, im, bb, bb, bb, bb, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT); //left= right= bottom= top = border = bb

    //=========================================================

    Mat dest = Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());

    int T = templeteWindowSize * templeteWindowSize;

    int count = T - 1;

    //step of template to image
    const int cstep = im.step - templeteWindowSize;

    for (int j = 0; j < src.rows; j++) {

        //src ptr
        uchar* d = dest.ptr(j);

        for (int i = 0; i < src.cols; i++) {

            uchar* tprt = im.data + im.step*(tr + j) + (tr + i); //pointer of image data amd step at 3x3 

            double tweight = 0.0;
            for (int n = templeteWindowSize; n--;)
            {
                for (int m = templeteWindowSize; m--;)
                {
                    tweight += *tprt++;
                }
                tprt += cstep;
            }
            tweight /= 9;
            *(d++) = (saturate_cast<uchar>(tweight) );
        }//i

    }//j    
    imshow("dest", dest);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input Image:**

[image]

**Output Image**

[image]

Problem: My image is not processed well by pointers. Can anyone correct my mistake in code. thanks

Can anyone please help me to correct my code. thanks .

Comment: try to apply diverse linear filters to smooth images using OpenCV functions such as:

    blur
    GaussianBlur
    medianBlur
    bilateralFilter

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html

Comment: Please i am interested to work with pointer .  on average smoothing only .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Mat src = imread("best-testimg.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

It seems only a third of the image is processed because you don't consider channel count.

Comment: Yes, you know that the image is gray scale, but you have to give imread() a hint, otherwise it returns an image with three identical channels.

Comment: Oh you , you are right. i  forgot to add IMREAD_GRAYSCALE .. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you would have to review your code. It seems to need an overhaul, for example:

- why intern_count
- why dest does not include the same tr step to avoid de border

In any case, take a look to the last line. You first saturate_cast before divide by 9. First divide, then cast.

Comment: Thanks, yes i have corrected it. and i will edit the code here too.

Comment: ok i have removed useless variables like intern_count . }
And also i edited border 'im' im image,. and get average and assign value to 'dest' image, which does not have border. . 

so that'sy i can not add same tr in dest image pointer.